# Let $F(x)=ln(x)\int_{0}^{x^{2}}(tan(x)+cos(t))dt$ Find $F'(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $F(x)=ln(x)\int_{0}^{x^{2}}(tan(x)+cos(t))dt$ Find $F'(x)$

We know:

$F(x)=ln(x)\int_{0}^{x^{2}}(tan(x)+cos(t))dt=ln(x)tan(x)\int_{0}^{x^{2}}dt+ln(x)\int_{0}^{x^{2}}cos(t)dt$

Let $A(x)=ln(x)tan(x)\int_{0}^{x^{2}}dt$ and $B(x)=ln(x)\int_{0}^{x^{2}}cos(t)dt$

Now i go to find $A'(x)$ and $B'(x)$

$A'(x)=(ln(x)tan(x))'\int_{0}^{x^{2}}dt+ln(x)tan(x)(\int_{0}^{x^{2}}dt)\text{'}=(\frac{tan(x)}{x}+ln(x)sec^{2}(x))\int_{0}^{x^{2}}dt+ln(x)tan(x)2x$

$B'(x)=(ln(x))'\int_{0}^{x^{2}}cos(t)dt+ln(x)(\int_{0}^{x^{2}}cos(t)dt)'=\frac{\int_{0}^{x^{2}}cos(t)dt}{x}+ln(x)cos(x^{2})2x$

Then,

$F'(x)=A'(x)+B'(x)=(\frac{tan(x)}{x}+ln(x)sec^{2}(x))\int_{0}^{x^{2}}dt+ln(x)tan(x)2x+\frac{\int_{0}^{x^{2}}cos(t)dt}{x}+ln(x)cos(x^{2})2x$

But i not sure if my result is fine, can someone help me?

Comment: I skimmed it quickly and it looks right. Just wanted to say you can simplfiy $\int_0^{x^2} dt = x^2$ and $\int_0^{x^2} \cos(t) dt$

Comment: Agree with ykm: Why so complicated? .The jntegral in A is x^2 and in B it is sin(x^2) so take it from there!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there is an easier way to go about solving this. In this case, it may be easier simply to evaluate the integral:
$$\int_0^{x^2}\big(\tan(x)+\cos(t)\big)dt=x^2\tan(x)+\sin(x^2)$$
and then substitute:
$$F(x)=\ln(x)(x^2\tan(x)+\sin(x^2))$$
and then differentiate:
$$F'(x)=\frac{1}{x}(x^2\tan(x)+\sin(x^2))+\ln(x)(2x\tan(x)+x^2\sec^2(x)+2x\cos(x))$$
$$F'(x)=x\tan(x)+\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}+\ln(x)(2x\tan(x)+x^2\sec^2(x)+2x\cos(x))$$
This may be a bit quicker, but I believe that our answers are equal.